# ifcf-ethx problem

Tags: linux, networking

Every time i run

```
service networkd restart
```

This is what i get

```
Shutting down interface eth0:  Device state: 3 (disconnected)
                                                           [  OK  ]
Shutting down interface eth1:                              [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:  Error org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.InvalidConnection: ifcfg file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' unknown
Error org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.InvalidConnection: ifcfg file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' unknown
Error org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.InvalidConnection: ifcfg file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' unknown
Error org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.InvalidConnection: ifcfg file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' unknown
                                                           [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:  Error org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.InvalidConnection: ifcfg file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' unknown
Error org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.InvalidConnection: ifcfg file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' unknown
Error org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.InvalidConnection: ifcfg file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' unknown
Error org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.InvalidConnection: ifcfg file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo' unknown
                                                           [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:
** (process:12951): WARNING **: fetch_connections_done: error fetching user connections: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerUserSettings was not provided by any .service files.
Active connection state: activating
Active connection path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
state: activated
Connection activated
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

Here is my ifcfg-eth0

```
# Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
DHCPCLASS=
HWADDR=xxx
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
ONBOOT=yes
OPTIONS=layer2=1
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=xxx
```

And my ifcfg-eth1

```
# Intel Corporation 82541PI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=xxx
ONBOOT=no
```

And my ifcfg-lo

```
DEVICE=lo
IPADDR=127.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
NETWORK=127.0.0.0
# If you're having problems with gated making 127.0.0.0/8 a martian,
# you can change this to something else (255.255.255.255, for example)
BROADCAST=127.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=loopback
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can see is this is a problem with Network Manager interacting with the ifdown/up scripts.  I suggest disabling Network Manager with

```
service NetworkManager stop
```

and see if that resolves it.  If you aren't using a wireless connection then you shouldn't need to use Network Manager anyway.  If that works, you can disable Network Manager permanently with

```
/sbin/chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

Answer (score 1):

Found [this with a google search](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=597515) for the error:

> ```
> # /etc/init.d/NetworkManager stop
>
> Add a BOOTPROTO=dhcp if you use dhcp to
> ```
>
> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-
>   or populate file with required values
>   for a static assignment
>
> ```
> # /etc/init.d/network start
>
> If the above works for you, you can make it the changes survive a
> ```
>
> reboot by doing:
>
> ```
> # chkconfig NetworkManager off
> # chkconfig network on
> ```